# Android Google Maps V2 Cluster hide infoWindow

Tags: android, google-maps, hide, cluster-computing, infowindow

In Android project, I'm using Google Maps Android API Utility Librairy in order to use clustering solution.

On each single marker or clustering marker an InfoWindow is opening on a touch on the selected marker. Then on a touch on the infoWindow I use theses events :

```
...
mClusterManager.setOnClusterInfoWindowClickListener(this);
mClusterManager.setOnClusterItemInfoWindowClickListener(this);
...
```

and :

```
@Override
public void onClusterInfoWindowClick(Cluster<JobItem> cluster) {
    // Here I go to a new fragment A, list of items.

}

@Override
public void onClusterItemInfoWindowClick(JobItem item) {
    // Here I go to a new fragment B, item's details

}
```

When I come back to the map (popBackStack from fragment A or B) the infoWindow is always open. I would like to hide them programmatically when I go to fragment A or B.
I found it's possible to call methods **hideInfoWindow()** from markers object but in theses two events markers are not passing through parameters.

Any idea on how to hide the infoWindow ?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that work for me, add this code on the onResume of your fragment, it will close all opened InfoWindow.

```
java.util.Collection<Marker> markerCollection = mClusterManager.getMarkerCollection().getMarkers();
for(Marker m : markerCollection){
    if(m.isInfoWindowShown())
    m.hideInfoWindow();
}
```